How to use a trained model in ChatGPT with a Spring Boot endpoint?
I'm using a trained model of ChatGPT code that works just fine within ChatGPT Playground, but when I try to use it with this code I developed I don't get the same results that I get on the ChatGPT Playground.
This is my code:
package com.em.tatamaster.dev.apichatgpt;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ApiChatgptApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApiChatgptApplication.class, args);
    }
}

The Controller:
package com.em.tatamaster.dev.apichatgpt;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@RestController
public class ChatController {

    @Qualifier("openaiRestTemplate")
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Value("${openai.model}")
    private String model;

    @Value("${openai.api.url}")
    private String apiUrl;

    @PostMapping("/chat")
    public String chat(@RequestParam String prompt) {
        ChatRequest request = new ChatRequest(model, prompt);
        request.setN(1); // Asegurar que n es al menos 1

        ChatResponse response = restTemplate.postForObject(apiUrl, request, ChatResponse.class);

        if (response == null || response.getChoices() == null || response.getChoices().isEmpty()) {
            return "No response";
        }
        return response.getChoices().get(0).getMessage().getContent();
    }
}

This is the version of the code that I'm not sure if it's meant to be like this because within it I'm sending a enhanced prompt that uses the prompt obtained by the other part of the project but my confusion is because When I send the prompt obtained by the other part of the project, I don't need to provide the enhancedPrompt but I'm going to leave the code like this so you can understand what I'm trying to obtain.
package com.em.tatamaster.dev.apichatgpt;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ChatRequest {

    private String model;
    private List<Message> messages;
    private int n = 1; // Valor predeterminado de 1
    private double temperature;

    public ChatRequest(String model, String prompt) {
        this.model = model;
        this.messages = new ArrayList<>();
        // Agregando el texto adicional al prompt
        String enhancedPrompt = prompt + " Retorna el nombre, apellido en el siguiente formato: " +
                "{\"nombre\":\"valor\", \"apellidos\":\"valor\", \"genero\":\"valor\", " +
                "\"fechaDeNacimiento\":\"valor\", \"fechaDeExpedicion\": \"valor\", \"fechaDeExpiracion\": \"valor\", " +
                "\"numeroDui\": \"valor\", \"departamento\":\"valor\", \"municipio\": \"valor\", \"tipoSangre\": \"valor\", " +
                "\"estadoFamiliaar\": \"valor\", \"carcteristicasEspeciales\": \"valor\", \"profesion\": \"valor\"}";
        this.messages.add(new Message("user", enhancedPrompt));
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public List<Message> getMessages() {
        return messages;
    }

    public void setMessages(List<Message> messages) {
        this.messages = messages;
    }

    public int getN() {
        return n;
    }

    public void setN(int n) {
        this.n = n;
    }

    public double getTemperature() {
        return temperature;
    }

    public void setTemperature(double temperature) {
        this.temperature = temperature;
    }
}

This is the ChatResponse:
package com.em.tatamaster.dev.apichatgpt;

import java.util.List;

public class ChatResponse {

    private List<Choice> choices;

    public ChatResponse() {
        super();
    }

    public ChatResponse(List<Choice> choices) {
        super();
        this.choices = choices;
    }

    public List<Choice> getChoices() {
        return choices;
    }

    public void setChoices(List<Choice> choices) {
        this.choices = choices;
    }

    public static class Choice {

        private int index;
        private Message message;

        public Choice() {
            super();
        }

        public Choice(int index, Message message) {
            super();
            this.index = index;
            this.message = message;
        }

        public int getIndex() {
            return index;
        }

        public void setIndex(int index) {
            this.index = index;
        }

        public Message getMessage() {
            return message;
        }

        public void setMessage(Message message) {
            this.message = message;
        }
    }
}

This is the Message class:
package com.em.tatamaster.dev.apichatgpt;

public class Message {

    private String role;
    private String content;

    public Message(String role, String content) {
        super();
        this.role = role;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public Message() {
        super();
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
}

And this is the OpenAIRestTemplateConfig class:
package com.em.tatamaster.dev.apichatgpt;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@Configuration
public class OpenAIRestTemplateConfig {

    @Value("${openai.api.key}")
    private String openaiApiKey;

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("openaiRestTemplate")
    public RestTemplate openaiRestTemplate() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.getInterceptors().add((request, body, execution) -> {
            request.getHeaders().add("Authorization", "Bearer " + openaiApiKey);
            return execution.execute(request, body);
        });
        return restTemplate;
    }
}

This is the prompt I get from the other part of the project:
[
    "REPUBLICA DE EL SALVADOR",
    "Documento Único de Identidad / ID",
    "Apellidos / Surname",
    "U",
    "LOPEZ AGUILAR",
    "Nombre / Given Names",
    "JOSE ROBERTO",
    "Conocido por / Known by",
    "Genero/Gender Salvadoreño por / Salvadorean by",
    "M",
    "NACIMIENTO",
    "Lugar y Fecha de Nacimiento / Place and Date of Birth",
    "SANTO TOMAS, SAN SALVADOR 20/10/1992",
    "Lugar , Fecha de Expedicion / Place and Date of Issuance",
    "SAN SALVADOR, SAN SALVADOR",
    "20/05/2022",
    "Fecha de Expracion / Date of Expiration",
    "19/05/2030",
    "Número March on ,",
    "JHL",
    "Unique ità number",
    "Firmit @ - Provide",
    "-",
    "04986307-1",
    "Hospital a Signature",
    "- -",
    "Departamento / State",
    "Tipo de sangre / Blood type",
    "NIT",
    "SAN SALVADOR",
    "Municipio / City",
    "Estado familiar / Marital status",
    "TONACATEPEQUE",
    "SOLTERO(A)",
    "Caracteristicas Especiales /",
    "Profesion/Profession",
    "Special Features:",
    "EMPLEADO(A)",
    "IDSLV04986307<<12<<<<<<<<<<<<<",
    "9210206M3005198SLV<<<<<<<<<<<0",
    "LOPEZ<AGUILAR<<JOSE<ROBERTO<<<"
]

And this is what I'm expecting to get with the use of the ChatGPT API:
{
        "apellidos": "LOPEZ AGUILAR",
        "nombre": "JOSE ROBERTO",
        "conocido(a)Por": "",
        "genero": "M",
        "fechaLugarDeNacimiento": "SANTO TOMAS, SAN SALVADOR 20/10/1992",
        "fechaDeExpedicion": "SAN SALVADOR, SAN SALVADOR 20/05/2022",
        "fechaDeExpiracion": "19/05/2030",
        "numeroDUI": "04986307-1",
        "nit": "",
        "dirección": "",
        "departamento": "SAN SALVADOR",
        "municipio": "TONACATEPEQUE",
        "tipoSangre": "-",
        "estadoFamiliar": "SOLTERO(A)",
        "caracteristicasEspeciales": "",
        "profesion": "EMPLEADO(A)"
}

Therefore what I'm trying to do with the use of the ChatGPT API is to arrange the data based on a specific pattern, and just to make it clear it works just fine on the ChatGPT Playground.
